# (Unofficial) StackExchange WWDC Meet Up — 7th June, 2011

Tags: discussion, meetups

**When:** Tuesday, 7th June 2011 (from 6pm, after the sessions finish)
**Location:** Eddie Rickenbacker's ([Google Maps Directions](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=moscone%20west&daddr=133%202nd%20St,%20San%20Francisco,%20CA%2094105&hl=en&geocode=FV6GQAIdE0e0-CEn9gyL1OYTtQ;FRyYQAId_Va0-CmPwA0sfYCFgDFciIsMAGT-TQ&mra=ltm&dirflg=w&sll=37.78475,-122.402835&sspn=0.006868,0.015686&ie=UTF8&ll=37.785292,-122.400613&spn=0.006868,0.015686&z=17)) ([yelp](http://www.yelp.com/biz/eddie-rickenbackers-san-francisco))

### [Sign Up Here](http://plancast.com/p/5ifv)

> 5000+ international Developers will be
> in San Francisco between 5th June and
> 11th. It seems like an ideal
> opportunity to have an unofficial
> StackExchange [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) / [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) / [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) / [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone)
> meet-up.

*NB: This is totally unofficial, please don't expect t-shirts and unicorn bucks*

Comment: I'm not attending WWDC (tix sold out before I could get boss's ok), but I'll be around at least one or two days that week to see friends. Someone pick a time & place, and I'll make it there if humanly possible.

Comment: Feel free to cross-post this on meta.apple.stackexchange.com - most of our members don't check Meta.SO

Comment: Your "When" needs more granularity.  Is this going to last all day?